# Invalid when I convert a data type in a generic function. toint is called, but the type of v is still double

Tags: scala, generics, casting, jackson, match

I want to implement a method to convert JSON data into Scala built-in objects. The code is similar to the following:

```scala
  implicit class JsonNodeToScala(jsonNode: JsonNode) {

    import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
    import scala.reflect.{ClassTag,classTag}

    def toSeq[T: ClassTag]: Seq[Option[T]] = jsonNode.elements.asScala.map(_.toScala[T]).toSeq

    def toMap[T: ClassTag]: Map[String, Option[T]] = jsonNode.fields.asScala.map(field => (field.getKey, field.getValue.toScala[T])).toMap

    def toScala[T: ClassTag]: Option[T] = (this.jsonNode match {
      case v if v.isBoolean => v.asBoolean
      case v if v.isNumber =>
        (v.asDouble, classTag.runtimeClass) match {
          case (v, c) if c == classOf[Int] => 
            print("toInt")
            v.toInt
          case (v, c) if c == classOf[Long] => 
            print("toLong")
            v.toLong
          case (v, _) => v
        }
      case v if v.isTextual => v.asText
      case jsonNode => jsonNode
    }) match {
      case v: T => Some(v)
      case v => 
        println(v, classTag.runtimeClass, v.getClass)
        None
    }
  }
```

*It works when I use it as follows*

```
new ObjectMapper().readTree("""[1,2,null,4]""").toSeq[Double]
>>> res136: Seq[Option[Double]] = List(
  Some(value = 1.0),
  Some(value = 2.0),
  None,
  Some(value = 4.0)
)
```

*But when I pass in the generic parameter int, I can't get the result I want.*

```
new ObjectMapper().readTree("""[1,2,null,4]""").toSeq[Int]
>>>
    toInt(1.0,int,class java.lang.Double)
    toInt(2.0,int,class java.lang.Double)
    (null,int,class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.NullNode)
    toInt(4.0,int,class java.lang.Double)
 
res138: Seq[Option[Int]] = List(None, None, None, None)
```

**As a result, toint is called, but the type of v is still double. Is it caused by Scala's processing in match case?**

**and if I want to meet my needs, how should I modify my code?**

```
"[1, 2, 3]" call toSeq[Int]  => Seq(1, 2, 3)
"[1, 2, 3]" call toSeq[Double]  => Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)

"[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]" call toSeq[Int]  => Seq(1, 2, 3)
"[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]" call toSeq[Double]  => Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that in:

```
case v if v.isNumber =>
  (v.asDouble, classTag.runtimeClass) match {
    case (v, c) if c == classOf[Int] => 
      print("toInt")
      v.toInt
    case (v, c) if c == classOf[Long] => 
      print("toLong")
      v.toLong
    case (v, _) => v
  }
```

The Scala compiler has to find the common lowest ancestor between `Int`, `Long` and `Double`.
In Scala 2.12, it happens to be `Double`, so it cast `Int` to `Double` again (via implicit conversion).
A way to *trick* the compiler should be to upcast some return type so it cannot perform an implicit type conversion between numerical types. For instance:

```
case v if v.isNumber =>
  (v.asDouble, classTag.runtimeClass) match {
    case (v, c) if c == classOf[Int] => 
      print("toInt")
      v.toInt
    case (v, c) if c == classOf[Long] => 
      print("toLong")
      v.toLong
    case (v, _) => (v : Any) // common lowest type now is Any, no conversions will be performed
  }
```